# Set a line size to a spooling in command windows

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper, spool

I'm using PL/SQL Developer version 11.0.6.1776

When I launch the script in my command window, the name of the file I'm spooling is incomplete.

This is the script I have:

```
set pagesize 0
set long 90000
SET TERMOUT OFF
spool out.sql

select 'spool C:\Users\personal\MAIN_USR\index\'||REPLACE(index_name, '$', '_')||'.txt'||chr(13)||chr(10)||
'SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(''INDEX'','''||index_name||''',''MTO_INDX'') '||chr(13)||chr(10)||
'FROM DUAL;'||chr(13)||chr(10)||
'spool off' as cmd
FROM user_indexes ui
INNER JOIN MTTO_TAB_EXIST_ALL tea USING(table_name)
WHERE tea.MRK_DEL_PERM = 'Y'
AND tea.OWNER_NM = 'MTO_INDX'
AND MCA_BACKUP_DDL != 'Y';

spool off

@OUT.SQL

exit
```

In the spooling, some files look like this below:

```
spool C:\Users\personal\MAIN_USR\index\CIA_PRD_PRDR_DISTR_INV_3242.t
```

The file extension should be .txt, but for some reason it is incomplete and other spooling files only have a part of the name

I appreciate any help to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Well, in SQL*Plus, it is e.g.

```
set linesize 100
```

which sets its length. I don't know whether it works in PL/SQL Developer as well.

On the other hand, even if line size is set to a low number (e.g. 50), SQL*Plus will "break" the line and move the rest of the text into the next line:

```
SQL> set linesize 50
SQL>
SQL> select 'spool C:\Users\personal\MAIN_USR\index\'||REPLACE(index_name, '$', '_')||'.txt'||chr(13)||chr(10)||
  2  'SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(''INDEX'','''||index_name||''',''MTO_INDX'') '||chr(13)||chr(10)||
  3  'FROM DUAL;'||chr(13)||chr(10)||
  4  'spool off' as cmd
  5  from (select 'i01_abc_omm' index_name from dual);

CMD
--------------------------------------------------
spool C:\Users\personal\MAIN_USR\index\i01_abc_omm
.txt                                                      --> see? Moved to the next line
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','i01_abc_omm'
,'MTO_INDX')
FROM DUAL;
spool off
```

That's why I'm not sure it'll actually help, but - you can try.